# How to real JSON from .gs file in Google Script App

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ecmascript-6

I am new to google app script. I want to read the below data from a **.gs file** in a google app script. I know how to read the content of an HTML file. Below are the contents of my file. and can anyone advise me on how to read data from a **.gs file?**

**json.gs**

```
const name = {
  "name1":"alex",
  "name2":"aqua",
  "name3":"verex"
}

const company = {
  "company1":"alex pvt ltd",
  "company2":"aqua pvt ltd",
  "company3":"verex pvt ltd"
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to read data from **.gs** file?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to read data from a .gs file in the google app script. I find a way to read HTML file content. Below is my file content.` and `Can anyone guide me on how to read data from .gs file?`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue and your goal?

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please see it again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. In your question, `name` and `company` are put in a script file `json.gs` and you want to retrieve those values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, I want to retrieve those values.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `yes, I want to retrieve those values.`, if your values of `name` and `company` are declared as the global variables, how about `function sample() {console.log(name); console.log(company);}`? By this, when `sample` is run, you can see the values in the log.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I want to access this JSON in the other .gs file. So this will work?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `But I want to access this JSON in the other .gs file. So this will work?`, if the `.gs` file is included in the same Google Apps Script project, the values can be retrieved from the functions in the other `.gs` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250803/discussion-between-yadav-shiv-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the JSON object defined globally in your project, it doesn't matter which file it is in, because it can be read from anywhere.

Let's take this example of two files in the same project: `Code.gs` and `consts.gs`

`consts.gs`:

```
const name = {
  "name1":"alex",
  "name2":"aqua",
  "name3":"verex"
}

const company = {
  "company1":"alex pvt ltd",
  "company2":"aqua pvt ltd",
  "company3":"verex pvt ltd"
}
```

`Code.gs`:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log(name.name1)
}
```

If you run `myFunction()`, then even though the function is defined in a different file to the JSON object called `name`, it will still be read and logged correctly.